# VB loops/if/random number program

Tags: vb.net, loops

I earlier posted about a question for the project, and here I am confused again. I am still just learning Visual Basic, and our teacher barely explained loops and how to use them. This is the program:

Create a Class Marks program that prompts the user for the number of students in the class. When the user clicks OK, the program should randomly generate a 9-digit student number that begins with "071" and marks between 30 and 100, and output the students number, marks and class average in a listbox control.

My code so far:

```
    Dim total As Integer = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim randomNumber As New Random

    Dim firstthree As String = "071"
    Dim first As Integer = randomNumber.Next(0, 9)
    Dim second As Integer = randomNumber.Next(0, 9)
    Dim third As Integer = randomNumber.Next(0, 9)
    Dim fourth As Integer = randomNumber.Next(0, 9)
    Dim fifth As Integer = randomNumber.Next(0, 9)
    Dim sixth As Integer = randomNumber.Next(0, 9)

    Dim grade As Integer = randomNumber.Next(30, 100)

    Dim studentNumber As String = firstthree & "-" & first & second & third & "-" & fourth & fifth & sixth

    Dim counter As Integer = 0

    If total = 5 Then
        Do While counter < 5
            Marks.Items.Add(studentNumber & vbTab & grade)

            counter += 1
        Loop
    End If
```

I'm still working on my code, I'm still learning so my code may not be the greatest. An issue I currently have is when I add the "studentNumber" and "grade" to the listbox they're all the same generated number when it should be all different. I don't know how to add up the grades in the listbox to find the average, so I have no idea on that part. [image]If someone could help with that issue and also help with developing the code and program it would be a blessing.

Thanks!

Comment: Work with data not controls.  After you add it, it is no longer a number *and* you have that extra text added.  Store the data in an array (or List) and do math on that

Comment: No wonder here, you loop 5 times adding always the same string. What did you expect to happen? If you want 5 different codes and grades then at each loop you should recalculate the whole _studentnumber_ and _grade_

Comment: how would I recalculate it?

Comment: @JaydenFerrer you need to calculate inside the loop, so that on each iteration it is a fresh calculation is made. As written, you run the calculation once and then use the same result on each iteration of the loop

Comment: `randomNumber.Next(0, 9)` produces values from `0` to `8`, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Hotfix:
Put the generation of random numbers *inside* the loop to get *different* random numbers for individual students. So instead of

```
        Do While counter < 5
            Marks.Items.Add(studentNumber & vbTab & grade)

            counter += 1
        Loop
```

use

```
        Do While counter < 5
            first  = randomNumber.Next(0, 9)
            second = randomNumber.Next(0, 9)
            third  = randomNumber.Next(0, 9)
            fourth = randomNumber.Next(0, 9)
            fifth  = randomNumber.Next(0, 9)
            sixth  = randomNumber.Next(0, 9)

            grade  = randomNumber.Next(30, 100)

            studentNumber = firstthree & "-" & first & second & third & "-" & fourth & fifth & sixth
            Marks.Items.Add(studentNumber & vbTab & grade)

            counter += 1
        Loop
```

Comment: `randomNumber.Next(0, 9)` produces values from `0` to `8`, BTW.

Comment: @Enigmativity you are right, of course. My answer doesn't pretend to be anything more than a hot-fix for the current OP's most pressing issue, so I copied / pasted his own code.

Answer (score 0):

You should represent the student as a Class to store the student's ID and marks as well as have a Function that returns the average of the marks. You can create the student ID and random marks in the Class's New constructor.

To create random marks between 30-100, use `Random.Next(30, 101)` which specifies that the lowest possible number should be 30 and the highest possible should be lower than 101.

Take a look at this console application example:

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1
    Private r As New Random
    Public Sub Main()
        'Declare a variable to keep track of the number of students
        Dim count As Byte = 0

        'Prompt for the number of students
        Console.Write("# of Students: ")

        'Loop until the user enters a valid value
        Do Until Byte.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), count) AndAlso count > 0
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number between 1 and 255")
        Loop

        'Loop through the count to create a new student and then display their respective ID and average
        For counter As Integer = 1 To count
            Dim s As New Student(r)
            Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} Average: {1}", s.ID, s.Average())
        Next
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class Student

    Public Property ID As String
    Public Property Marks As Integer()

    Public Function Average() As Double
        'Declare a placeholder variable to keep track of the total
        Dim total As Double = 0

        'Loop through each value in the collection
        For Each mark As Double In Me.Marks
            'Increment the total variable
            total += mark
        Next

        'Return the average
        Return total / Me.Marks.Length
    End Function

    Public Sub New(ByVal r As Random)
        'Set the ID to a 9 digit code starting with 071, separated by hyphens after every third number
        Me.ID = "071-" & 
                r.Next(0, 10) & r.Next(0, 10) & r.Next(0, 10) & "-" &
                r.Next(0, 10) & r.Next(0, 10) & r.Next(0, 10)

        'Create 10 random values between 30-100
        ReDim Me.Marks(9)
        For counter As Integer = 1 To 10
            Me.Marks(counter - 1) = r.Next(30, 101)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BGdQOF)

Comment: The student is just trying to learn loops. Probably, classes come later. If he did use a class, I don't think the function for the class average belongs in the Student class.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, good catch. I've gone ahead and edited the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see a few of the problems you're running into.

## 1

```
'For loop
For n As Integer = 1 To Integer.Parse(numStudents)
    'Here, n will increment with every iteration of the loop, and stop when i > numStudents
    'This is where you'll want to calculate the ID number for each student.
Next
```

## 2

```
randomNumber.Next(0, 9)
```

Is returning a random number between values 0 and 8. This will get you what you need if you do as you have in your code inside the loop, but I'd suggest you'd get the same results but more concise by using

```
studNumber = prefix & "-" & randomNumber.Next(0, 999).ToString("D3") & "-" & randomNumber.Next(0, 999).ToString("D3")
```

## 3

If you need the class average, you'll probably want to store the total number of students, and the individual scores of each. Something like:

```
Dim totStudents, totPoints, classAvg, points As Integer
'Get totStudents from input

totPoints = 0

For i As Integer = 1 To Integer.Parse(totStudents)
    points = rando.Next(30, 100)
    totPoints += points 'totPoints is now whatever value it used to be plus the value of points
    'This is also where you want to get the student's ID number and add it to the listbox.
Next

classAvg = totPoints / totStudents
```

I think if you put those three together the right way it'll give you what you're looking for. Hope it helps.

Comment: `randomNumber.Next(0, 9)` produces numbers from `1` to `8`, not `9`.

Comment: You also haven't addressed the issue that the OP asked about.